# Android: Live Stream Video URL Player

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming

We are trying to develop an app for Android where you can play a live streaming URL. I tried several approaches using the MediaPlayer and StreamPlayer... but no luck with the URL playing.

I can of cause play a static MP4 or MP3 file using the URL (hosted on a server) but when I try to play a stream URL it doesn't play or give an error.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try playing your stream in Daroon player. It surely works.

Comment: Do you have the source code for daroon player?

Comment: I know that ... Exactly my question, do u have the source code for that player? Or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mp3 stream works well on Mediaplayer  from  Android 2.2 and above.  If you want to play the Content below 2.2 then its better to use local proxy server implementation. check [Npr](http://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/) . Which uses the same approach.

If you want to play wma audio you should convert that into PCM and play it. check [aacplaye](http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/)r. In aacplayer project he gets wma content from mms:// stream and plays it . You can edit that to play only wma content. But i haven't tried playing any wmv videos.

Comment: Well i'm targeting 2.2 and above. So no issues there, but when i try to play a URL (http://220.247.244.204:8000) it doesn't play in my android device .... any ideas?

Comment: @megazoid The above Url is not opening here. Which format you are trying to play?. Raw ADTS aac streams are not supported below android 4.0. And its not possible to play wma streams too. Can you share one more url which i can try?

Comment: the stream is WMV, but there are players like DAROOM which is able to play this stream on my android device. I know that WMA and WMV won't directly play on Android as Android has decided not to support Windows Media formats on their devices for some odd reason. But how does other players play WMV's on the android? This is what i'm trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: You can certainly play wma audio by converting it into PCM. But i have not checked WMV videos. Editing my answer